# Resize StringElement value in MonoTouch Dialog

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is there anyway to auto resize the value of a string element in MonoTouch. I'm using them in two ways :

1st- with reflection

2nd- manually adding stringelement to a section
but both can contains value (or caption) that cannot be fitted in the displayed area.

[image: http://hpics.li/479e85c]

What is the best way to handle an elegant display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `MultilineElement` instead of `StringElement`